# How to connect to SQL Server database with C++ Builder

Tags: sql-server, c++builder

How can I connect to a SQL Server Database using C++ Builder?

When I drop SQLConnection component, I can't find a place to drop my connection string in... And how can I type a connection string in C++ Builder? Is it the same that in C#?

Comment: Read the documentation: [Setting Up TSQLConnection](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Setting_Up_TSQLConnection).

Answer (score 0):

Use ADO components. You can use TADOConnection component where you can input your connection string and then add TADOTable for each database table or TADOQuery for SQL queries. Both TADOTable and TADOQuery have a Connection property where you will chose your TADOConnection component.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the TADOConnection component in your VCL form or Database form, you can click on the link in the Properties window to Edit ConnectionString.  Otherwise you can right click on the object in the form and click Edit ConnectionString there.  A ConnectionString dialog box will be displayed that lets you either connect to a data file or Use a Connection String.  You want to use a connection string.  There you can either paste in your old connection string and see if it works or use the Build... button on the right to select a provider such as SQL Server Native Client 11.0, then click Next>>.  Then in the Connection tab select all the connection parameters and use the Test Connection button to actually test it.  This is much better than trying to debug the connection in your application.  Once it is working, save it by clicking on the OK button.

Answer (score -1):

To connect to a MySQL server, drop a TSQLConnection component (in the 
DBExpress palatte page) to your form, chose the ConnectionName as 
MySQLConnection, DriverName as MySQL and set the Params according to this:

-if you are connecting to your local computer:

- HostName - localhost (or 127.0.0.1 or your local computer name)

-or if you are connecting to a remote computer:

- HostName - (your remote server's domain name)

-These will be same regardless of local or remote connection:

- Database - (the database name you want to connect to)

User_Name - (your database user name, or log in name)

- Password - (the password to access your database)

You can leave the rest at default unless you have other requirements.

Comment: i did what you said but i got this error http://www12.0zz0.com/2015/07/11/05/683015025.jpg , i got it when i try to edit ConnectionName property too..what's wrong ?

Comment: and when i try to set Driver property to MySql i get this error http://www14.0zz0.com/2015/07/11/05/449273104.jpg

Comment: The question was how to connect to **SQLServer**, not to **MYSQL**.

Comment: @RemyLebeau then what is the right solution for my problem ?

Comment: @Kordy: Did you read the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Setting_Up_TSQLConnection)?

Comment: @RemyLebeau i read it and set my connection setting but when i try to connect to the db i get this error [image link](http://www14.0zz0.com/2015/07/13/07/270184871.jpg)

Comment: @Kordy: Did you install the SQLServer client library and the SQLServer DBX driver on the target machine?  It is not enough to just install your app by itself, you need the database drivers as well. This is clearly stated in the documentation I linked to.